# How to display the min and max values of integers read from a file?

Tags: c++

Below is my code. I have a problem in my alogrithm. It displays the last value of the integer from the input file for both the max and min. values. Would someone please take a look and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
#include "cstdlib"
#include "iostream"
#include "fstream"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream instream;
    ofstream outstream;
    instream.open("num.txt");
    if(instream.fail())
    {
        cout<<"The input file failed to open\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    outstream.open("output.txt");
    if(outstream.fail())
    {
        cout<<"The output file failed to open";
        exit(1);
    }

    int next, largest, smallest;
    largest = 0;
    smallest = 0;

    while(instream>>next)
    {
        largest = next;
        smallest = next;
        if(largest<next)
        {
            largest = next;
        }
        if(smallest>next)
        {
            smallest = next;
        }
    }

    outstream<<"The largest number is: "<<largest<<endl;
    outstream<<"The smallest number is: "<<smallest<<endl;
    instream.close();
    outstream.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, please fix the formatting.

Comment: Please have a look at [the difference in formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10993666/revisions) of your question. Next time make sure you do this yourself. @jrok, you might not want to fix the code in the question.

Comment: @Bart I supposed it was just a typo, OP seems to have typed the code instead of copy pasting. Feel free to unroll, though.

Comment: Please **stop** editing errors _out_ of the _question_, I made a final edit to preserve the correct formatting while duplicating the code that the _op_ originally posted. If the OP says it was a pasting error, fine .. but if that's his _actual_ code ...

Answer (score 2):

You unconditionally assign the value of `next` to `largest` and `smallest` in every iteration:

```
while(instream>>next)
    {
        largest = next;    //  <--  Why are you surprised?
        smallest = next;   //  <--  :)
        if(largest<next)
        {
            largest = next;
        }
        if(smallest>next)
        {
            smallest = next;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Programs tend to do what they are told to. This is what you told to do:

```
while(instream>>next) {
        largest = next;
        smallest = next;
```

This is where you always set them to latest. Maybe change those three lines to this:

```
largest = 0;
smallest = –0;
while(instream>>next) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Could the problem be in this loop?

```
    while(instream>>next)

    {

    largest = next;

    smallest = next;

    if(largest<next)

    {

    largest = next;

    }

    if(smallest>next)

    {

      smallest = next;

    }

    }
```

Wouldnt the 2 if statements not be reachable because largest and smallest are both equal to next? If the 2 if statements in the while are never executed, the largest and smallest would always be set to next on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<cstdlib>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream instream;
    ofstream outstream;
    instream.open("joy.txt");
    if(instream.fail())
    {
        cout<<"The input file failed to open\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    outstream.open("output.txt");
    if(outstream.fail())
    {
        cout<<"The output file failed to open";
        exit(1);
    }

    int next, largest, smallest;
    largest = 0;
    smallest = 0;


    while(instream>>next)
    {

        if(largest<next)
        {
            largest = next;
        }else{
                  smallest = next;
        }
    }

    outstream<<"The largest  number is: "<<largest<<endl;
    outstream<<"The smallest number is: "<<smallest<<endl;
    instream.close();
    outstream.close();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```